# Troubleshooting Gurobi Import Errors in Jupyter Notebook on Compute Canada HPC server

Tags: gurobi, gurobipy, high-performance-computing

I am trying to use Gurobi optimization software in a Jupyter notebook on a Compute Canada HPC server, but I am running into issues importing the gurobipy module in Python.

I have loaded the Gurobi module successfully using 'module load gurobipy' in Mobaxterm, and I can see the license is correctly set up. However, when I try to import gurobipy in a Jupyter notebook, I get an error saying "No module named gurobipy".

Additionally, when I try to install gurobipy using 'pip install gurobipy', I get error messages saying the package cannot be found.

I have reviewed the Gurobi documentation on the Compute Canada wiki (https://docs.alliancecan.ca/wiki/Gurobi), including the Jupyter notebook instructions and video tutorial, but I am still unsure how to resolve this import issue within my Jupyter environment.

**How do I install and configure Gurobi and the gurobipy module so it can be imported correctly in a Jupyter notebook on Compute Canada?**

Comment: +1 but Compute Canada machines are servers that are meant to be accessed via a terminal, not a GUI. I do not recommend to use Jupyter notebooks on Compute Canada servers. Why not just use a terminal like nearly everyone else in the HPC community?

Comment: From the [slides](https://helpwiki.sharcnet.ca/wiki/images/c/c6/JupyterOnCluster-Qin.pdf), it seems that they are installing `gurobipy` without pip on the virtualenv (slide 10).